# Reverse Linked list - Null pointer exception

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

I am writing a Java function to reverse a linked list in-place. I am new to Java and fail to be successfully debug the bug in the function below. The IDE returns a *NullPointerException* that I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public listNode reverseLinkedList(listNode head)
{
    listNode reversedLinkedList = head;
    listNode temp = null;

    while (reversedLinkedList != null) {
        reversedLinkedList.setNext(temp);
        temp = reversedLinkedList;
        reversedLinkedList = reversedLinkedList.getNext();    
    }
    return reversedLinkedList;
}
```

For testing, I have a linked list intialized already with 8 linked nodes. In the function above, I am trying to swap the next pointers between each nodes and move `reversedLinkedList` pointer along the linked list.

EDIT: Some have suggested that I use debugger to identify where the `NullPointerException` occurs. I already did that. It occurs in the line `reversedLinkedList = reversedLinkedList.getNext();` in the second iteration of the `while` loop.

I initialized the linked list with 8 pointers for testing. The `while` loop, instead of going to the second node, instead sees a `null` pointer. It may have something to do with the *temp* variable but I am not sure.

Comment: If you run it in the debugger, it should halt on the line with the exception, giving you plenty of clues.

Comment: As Oli pointed out, you should get a specific line telling you where the exception occurs. By glancing over it, make sure that (if the list is singly-linked) you aren't de-referencing a node before you switch its pointers -- that would just clear the list (except for head).

Comment: So should the exception stack trace. ;)

Comment: Some have suggested that i use debugger to identify where the nullexception occurs. I already did that. It occurs in the line "reversedLinkedList = reversedLinkedList.getNext();" in the second iteration of the while loop

I initialized the linked list with 8 pointers for testing. The while loop, instead of going to the second node, instead sees a null pointer. It may have something to do with the temp variable but i am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is flaw in your reasoning. When you (first step)

```
reversedLinkedList.setNext(temp)
```

You are changing the first reference to null (which is correct) but you loose any reference to the next pointer. Two lines later you

```
reversedLinkedList = reversedLinkedList.getNext();
```

`temp` was null so `reversedLinkedList` will be null.

You need to store the next pointer to the temporary variable *before* changing it.

But this is not causing an exception. Please post the complete code **and** the stack trace of the exception

Comment: i get it. Thanks. Trivial bug at the end. cant believe i missed it

Comment: I think this is causing the exception, because in the next iteration `reversedLinkedList.setNext(temp);` is executed. And since `reversedLinkedList` was set to `null` as you mentioned ...

Comment: @BenvanGompel should not since the loop is guarded by `reversedLinkedList != null`. This is why I said that this code is most likely not causing the exception.

Comment: @Matteo, yeah you're correct. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you;

- Read the error message to find the exact line the NullPointerException occurs.
- Use the debugger to step through the code and see why the variable is null.

There isn't any code here which can produce a null pointer exception so I assume you are looking in the wrong place.  I suggest you follow the two steps above instead of guessing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be with the final node, you will not be able to get the next node since its NULL!

```
 reversedLinkedList = reversedLinkedList.getNext();
```

Not sure though!

Comment: No this will not raise an exception: `reversedLinkedList` will be just be null